# Can one modify the default repr behavior through a metaclass?

Tags: python

I would like to customize the output of `repr(x)` for instances `x` of a certain family of classes.  (FWIW, these classes inherit from `long`.)

I already use a metaclass to control other aspects of these classes.  Is there a way I can include the custom `repr` behavior as part of the definition of the metaclass?

Comment: Do they inherit from the metaclass first, or `long`?

Comment: "Dumb" question, did you try def __ repr __ (without spaces)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, clsbase, clsdict):
        newcls = super().__new__(cls, clsname, clsbase, clsdict)
        def custom_repr(self):
            return '{}, Custom __repr__'.format(clsname)
        newcls.__repr__ = custom_repr
        return newcls

class Foo(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

Python 2.X:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, clsbase, clsdict):
        newcls = super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, clsbase, clsdict)
        def custom_repr(self):
            return '{}, Custom __repr__'.format(clsname)
        newcls.__repr__ = custom_repr
        return newcls

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

for example:

```
>>> Foo()
Foo, Custom __repr__
>>>
```